# Silverlight toolkit - intercepting drag start

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

I can't find a way to intercept the beginning of the drag operation in SLToolkit; I need that in order for my custom controls to indicate the regions where the item could be dropped. Unfortunately, there is no IsDragInProgressChanged event; I looked at the sources and the only way I found was to subclass all DragDropTarget<,>s and override OnItemDragStarting method, which, in my opinion, is way too complicated and intrusive. Anyone knows of a better method?

Answer (score 1):

Both the PanelDragDropTarget and ListBoxDragDropTarget have an event named *ItemDragStarting*. Adding an event handler in the XAML and handling it in the code-behind should be all you need.